# Sentence structure _From what for

Tags: sentence-construction

Their valet service helped smooth the transition to the school day *from what for many kids was a raucous home environment*

What kind of function is the italicized part in the sentence above? it is a Noun clause or Adverbial Clause？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *from what for many kids was a raucous home environment*

is neither a noun clause nor an adverbial clause; it is a preposition phrase.

The **what-clause** embedded in this preposition phrase is the noun clause you probably want to ask about.   This is the object of preposition *from*.